Unable to Connect to Wireguard VPN
I am trying to set up a VPN through WireGuard so that I can access a server remotely.
I have the server running Ubuntu Server 24.02 on a Mac Mini and would like to connect with my Windows laptop from another network. I have followed the guide here (https://docs.vultr.com/how-to-install-wireguard-vpn-on-ubuntu-24-04). My current config is below. My problem is that I cannot seem to get a connection even though everything before that step seems to have worked correctly. When I try to activate the tunnel through the WireGuard GUI it activates but I get no response from the server.
On my server, I have this config:
[Interface] 
Address = 10.8.0.1/24

SaveConfig = true

PrivateKey = server private key

PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on enp1s0

PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on enp1s0

PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]

PublicKey = client public key

AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/24

On my laptop, I have this configuration:
[Interface]

PrivateKey = client private key

Address = 10.8.0.2/24

DNS = 8.8.8.8


[Peer]

PublicKey = server public key

AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

Endpoint = <public ip of server>:51820

PersistentKeepalive = 15

I have tried to search why this may be happening but this is my first networking project so I am pretty lost. Can anyone point me to some steps I should take to start finding a solution?

If there is actually a firewall in effect, obviously you need to allow the udp dport 51820 traffics to get into the server too. Also, is the server bebind a home router? And were you checking with wg or 10.8.0.1?

I believe I allowed udp on 51820 using $ufw allow 51820/udp. Yes the server is behind a CODA-4582-RES router. I was using the wireguard windows gui to test the connection and I also tried pinging 10.8.0.1. Neither were successful.
